# Изменение сортировки по умолчанию (php)

Tags: php, битрикс

Хочу сменить сортировку на сайте с "по-умолчанию" на "сначала дорогие". Долго возился, но не смог сделать сам. Вот код выпадающего меню

```
<select id="select_sort">
<option value="base">По умолчанию</option>                      
<option value="price_desc"<?if ($_REQUEST["sort"] == "price_desc") echo " selected";?>>Сначала дорогие</option> 
<option value="price_asc"<?if ($_REQUEST["sort"] == "price_asc") echo " selected";?>>Сначала дешевые</option>
<option value="new"<?if ($_REQUEST["sort"] == "new") echo " selected";?>>Новинки</option>
<option value="bestseller"<?if ($_REQUEST["sort"] == "bestseller") echo " selected";?>>Хиты продаж</option>
<option value="sale"<?if ($_REQUEST["sort"] == "sale") echo " selected";?>>Со скидкой</option>
</select>
```

Вот код скрипта, который отвечает за сортировку (по крайней мере я так понял)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#select_count").change(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() != "")
        {
                var base_location = "<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("count=#count#",array("count"))?>";
                base_location = base_location.replace("#count#", $(this).val());
                document.location = base_location;  
        }
    }
    );

    $("#select_sort").change(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
        {
                var base_location = "<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("",array("sort"))?>";
        }
        else
        {
                var base_location = "<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("sort=#sort#",array("sort"))?>";
                base_location = base_location.replace("#sort#", $(this).val());
        }
        document.location = base_location;  
    }
    );

}
);
</script>
```

Подскажите, что нужно изменить в скрипте, чтобы изначально товары на странице сортировались по цене (от большей)

Comment: Код компонента приведите. В кусках того что вы запостили нет явного указания для сортировки в компоненте. Только события изменения селекта и сам селект

Comment: Т.е код вызова компонента. Код шаблона компонента не нужен

Comment: Я c php не сильно дружу. Сам компонент находится в catalog.section. В компоненте выше (catalog) нашел код <?$intSectionID = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
  //"citrus:catalog.section",
  //"toysales",
  
  "toysales:catalog.section",
  "",
  
  array(
   "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
   "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],

это оно?

Comment: да - приведите полный вызов компонента

Comment: привел в ответе ниже

Comment: "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD"],
            "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER"], - это параметры компонента каталог должны быть - если эти параметры нгде не переопределеяются то вы самомстоятельно можете выставить это в настройках родительского компонента

Comment: Что делать после добавления этих строк в поля компонента?

Comment: В файле где обявлен этот компонент данные параметры не переопределеяются? Если нет, то посмотрите что указано в в компоненте каталог для этих параметров

Answer (score -1):

```
<?$intSectionID = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
        //"citrus:catalog.section",
        //"toysales",

        "toysales:catalog.section",
        "",

        array(
            "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
            "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
            "VENDORS_IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["VENDORS_IBLOCK_ID"],
            "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD"],
            "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER"],
            "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2"],
            "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2"],
            "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD3" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD3"],
            'ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER3' => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER3"],      
            "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_PROPERTY_CODE"],
            "META_KEYWORDS" => $arParams["LIST_META_KEYWORDS"],
            "META_DESCRIPTION" => $arParams["LIST_META_DESCRIPTION"],
            "BROWSER_TITLE" => $arParams["LIST_BROWSER_TITLE"],
            "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => $arParams["SET_LAST_MODIFIED"],
            "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => $arParams["INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS"],
            "BASKET_URL" => $arParams["BASKET_URL"],
            "ACTION_VARIABLE" => $arParams["ACTION_VARIABLE"],
            "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => $arParams["PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE"],
            "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => $arParams["SECTION_ID_VARIABLE"],
            "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"],
            "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => $arParams["PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE"],
            "FILTER_NAME" => $arParams["FILTER_NAME"],
            "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
            "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
            "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
            "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
            "SET_TITLE" => $arParams["SET_TITLE"],
            "MESSAGE_404" => $arParams["MESSAGE_404"],
            "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
            "SHOW_404" => $arParams["SHOW_404"],
            "FILE_404" => $arParams["FILE_404"],
            "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => $arParams["USE_COMPARE"],
            "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => $arParams["PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT"],
            "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => $arParams["LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT"],
            "PRICE_CODE" => $arParams["PRICE_CODE"],
            "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => $arParams["USE_PRICE_COUNT"],
            "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => $arParams["SHOW_PRICE_COUNT"],

            "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => $arParams["PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE"],
            "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => $arParams['USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY'],
            "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => (isset($arParams["ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET"]) ? $arParams["ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET"] : ''),
            "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => (isset($arParams["PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES"]) ? $arParams["PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES"] : ''),
            "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => $arParams["PRODUCT_PROPERTIES"],

            "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"],
            "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"],
            "PAGER_TITLE" => $arParams["PAGER_TITLE"],
            "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS"],
            "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["PAGER_TEMPLATE"],
            "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING"],
            "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME"],
            "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALL"],
            "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE"],
            "PAGER_BASE_LINK" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK"],
            "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => $arParams["PAGER_PARAMS_NAME"],

            "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => $arParams["OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES"],
            "OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE"],
            "OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE"],
            "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => $arParams["OFFERS_SORT_FIELD"],
            "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => $arParams["OFFERS_SORT_ORDER"],
            "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => $arParams["OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2"],
            "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => $arParams["OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2"],
            "OFFERS_LIMIT" => $arParams["LIST_OFFERS_LIMIT"],

            "SECTION_ID" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"],
            "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
            //"SECTION_CODE_PATH" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE_PATH"],

            "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
            "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["element"],
            "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => $arParams["USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION"],
            'CONVERT_CURRENCY' => $arParams['CONVERT_CURRENCY'],
            'CURRENCY_ID' => $arParams['CURRENCY_ID'],
            'HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE' => $arParams["HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE"],

            'LABEL_PROP' => $arParams['LABEL_PROP'],
            'ADD_PICT_PROP' => $arParams['ADD_PICT_PROP'],
            'PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE' => $arParams['PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE'],

            'OFFER_ADD_PICT_PROP' => $arParams['OFFER_ADD_PICT_PROP'],
            'OFFER_TREE_PROPS' => $arParams['OFFER_TREE_PROPS'],
            'PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION' => $arParams['PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION'],
            'SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => $arParams['SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT'],
            'SHOW_OLD_PRICE' => $arParams['SHOW_OLD_PRICE'],
            'MESS_BTN_BUY' => $arParams['MESS_BTN_BUY'],
            'MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET' => $arParams['MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET'],
            'MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE' => $arParams['MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE'],
            'MESS_BTN_DETAIL' => $arParams['MESS_BTN_DETAIL'],
            'MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE' => $arParams['MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'],

            'TEMPLATE_THEME' => (isset($arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME']) ? $arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME'] : ''),
            "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => $arParams['ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN'],
            'ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION' => $basketAction,
            'SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP' => isset($arParams['COMMON_SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP']) ? $arParams['COMMON_SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP'] : '',
            'COMPARE_PATH' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['compare'],
            'BACKGROUND_IMAGE' => (isset($arParams['SECTION_BACKGROUND_IMAGE']) ? $arParams['SECTION_BACKGROUND_IMAGE'] : ''),
            'IMAGE_WIDTH' => (isset($arParams['SECTION_IMAGE_WIDTH']) ? $arParams['SECTION_IMAGE_WIDTH'] : ''),
            'IMAGE_HEIGHT' => (isset($arParams['SECTION_IMAGE_HEIGHT']) ? $arParams['SECTION_IMAGE_HEIGHT'] : ''),
            'DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT' => (isset($arParams['DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT']) ? $arParams['DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT'] : ''),
        ),
        $component
    );?>
```